# Wrote alternative to jQuery Accordion, it spazzed. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote an alternative to the jQuery Accordion, as that didn't offer multiple open section support (any idea why they opted to not include support for that? What's the history there?). I did some research on StackOverflow, as well on Google to see what other options others came up. I needed something that could be used on the fly on multiple elements.

After seeing several solutions and experimenting with them, in the end, I wrote my own version (based on Kevin's solution from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-multiple-sections-open-at-once , but heavily modified).

jsFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/3jacu/1/

Inline Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.fn.togglepanels = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        h4handler = $(this).find("h4");
        $(h4handler).prepend('<div class="accordionarrow">&#9660;</div>');
        $(h4handler).click(function() {
            $(h4handler).toggle(
                function() {
                    barclicked = $(this);
                    $(barclicked).find(".accordionarrow").html('&#9658;');
                    $(barclicked).next().slideUp('slow');
                    window.console && console.log('Closed.');
                    return false;
                }, 
                function() {
                    barclicked = $(this);
                    $(barclicked).find(".accordionarrow").html('&#9660;');
                    $(barclicked).next().slideDown('slow');
                    window.console && console.log('Open.');
                    return false;
                }
            );
        });
    });
};

$("#grouplist").togglepanels(); }
```

Oddly, the accordion arrow at the right side stopped working once I pasted it in jsFiddle, while it works in my local copy.

In any case, the issue is that toggling isn't working as expected, and when it does, it fires duplicate toggle events which result in it closing, opening, then ultimately closing the section and it won't open from that point on (it toggles open then closes back). That's assuming it works! At first, it won't work as it doesn't respond. I think there's a logic error somewhere I'm missing.

From what I wrote/see in the code, it searches the given handle for the corresponding tag (in this case, h4), pops the handle into a variable. It then adds the arrow to the h4 tag while applying the accordionarrow class (which floats it to the right). It then adds a click event to it, which will toggle (using jQuery's toggle function) between two functions when h4 is clicked.

I suspect the problem here is that I may be mistakenly assuming jQuery's toggle function will work fine for toggling between two functions, that I'll have to implement my own toggle code. Correct me if I'm wrong though!

I'm trying to write the code so it'll be as efficient as possible, so feedback on that also would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time, assistance, and consideration!

Comment: hey, your jsfiddle is missing a final `);` to close the document ready call, that's why nothing is working at the moment.

Comment: As far as general code style and efficiency goes you'd be better off working off of existing code.  Your variable scoping is shaky.  You should be using the `event` object (as a parameter) to target your event handlers (`event.target` or `event.currentTarget`).  Using `this` is less certain and carries less intent.  You have extraneous jQuery wrapping which is entirely wasteful: after  `barclicked = $(this);` just use `barclicked` without the `$()` which wraps what is already a wrapper each time (or even better use `$barclicked` to signify that that is a wrapper).

Comment: You also shouldn't be attaching handlers directly to the elements, but instead using `.on` and matching `click`s with the proper selector.  The visibility can then be modified using the still supported other `toggle` method (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), and the arrow swapped on the callback.  Unless there's a good reason not to the arrow would likely also be better initially added using CSS and markup (and having it within the h4 could be misleading from a conventional and a semantic standpoint).  Also make sure to look at the HTML5 `detail` element if you aren't aware of it.

Comment: And just to really hammer that last point home: using a `detail` element with desired styling and an existing polyfill will certainly be far and away **the most** efficient solution moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `toggle` binding (which is deprecated by the way) inside of the `click` binding, so a new event handler is getting attached every time you click the header.

As a random aside you should also fire events within the plugin (where you have the console lines would make sense) so that external code can react to state changes.

Comment: Just checked jQuery docs, does show as deprecated. But it fails to say what should be used instead. Can you suggest a modern solution for click toggle, or should I just use .on in conjunction with click/selector matching and a variable toggle?

Comment: You can just use the other `toggle` on the `click` event (ideally using `on`) as linked to in the comments and then use an `.is(":visible")` in the callback to that function to update the display accordingly (or accordianly if you like bad jokes).  Don't track state when you don't need to.

Comment: I may be clueless here, so please pardon me for that. I used toggle, but you mentioned other toggle; but you also said toggle is deprecated. I'm thinking you may be referring to a different functionality with the same name. You're saying that the mouse toggle event is deprecated, so where is this other toggle functionality? Would you mind linking to the jQuery docs in where this current non-deprecated toggle functionality is?

Comment: The link above in the comments above is a link to the proper function.  It alternates visibility.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does answer my question. I opted to remove the click and toggle, and instead just use .on("click" in conjunction with a variable toggle which allowed me to toggle functions. My code is now working as expected. I also applied the wrapper change you advised. I'm still trying to wrap my head around using event.target/event.currentTarget instead of 'this'. Will research this though, but if you want to share a good doc explaining why that approach is better than 'this', it'd be appreciated. I'm not an expert, and always am open to learning.

Comment: For those who come across this while searching: current toggle is http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ . Doesn't include function toggle, as that has been deprecated. Just use .on in conjunction with a variable toggle, it'll achieve the same effect.

Comment: Preferring `event` over `this` is a matter of preference. IMO it's more emphatic as `event` has more explicit meaning than `this`, and depending on how delegation is working it can also provide more reliable information. Because `this` is more variable it can be left to be used for other purposes. In an MVC style app you may want `this` to remain bound to the View to have access to other members within the handler. It could also be used for mixin-style handlers to be reused in different contexts.  This is outside of this use though (and is still preference), so just stick with what you like.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that! It's most certainly much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to paste the trailing characters `);` to close the function call to jQuery function `ready`. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/LeZuse/3jacu/2/
UPDATE: I've just realised I did not really answer your question.
You are duplicating the .toggle functionality with binding another .click handler.
The doc about [.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) says:

> Description: Bind two or more handlers to the matched elements, to be executed on alternate clicks.

Which means the click event is already built in.
NOTE: You should use local variables instead of global, so your plugin won't pollute the window object. Use the `var` keyword for this:
`var h4handler = $(this).find("h4");`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is the `$(h4handler).click(function() {` you have wrapped around the `toggle` listener. Essentially what this was doing was making so every click of the tab was adding the toggle listener, which was then also firing an event. Removing the click listener will have the behaviour you expect.